# Writing float numbers into csv file in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, csv, floating-point

I am trying to create a CSV file in nodejs from json data that I get from database.

I create an array of objects as my data

```
var allExpenses = [];
expenses.forEach(function(expense) {
            allExpenses.push({
                amount: expense.amount,
                identificator: expense.identificator,
                person: expense.person.last_name + ' ' + expense.person.first_name,
                date: moment.tz(expense.date, "Europe/Budapest").format("D.M.YYYY"),
                description: expense.description || '-'
            });
        });
```

then I use json2csv module to create csv data and write it to file via fs

```
//create csv
var csvFields = ['amount', 'identificator', 'person', 'date', 'description'];
var csv = require('json2csv')({data: allExpenses, fields: csvFields, del: ';'});

var filename = new Date().valueOf() + '_csv_expenses.csv';
var filepath = config.path + '/reports/' + filename;
fs.writeFile(filepath, '\ufeff' + csv, 'utf-8', function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500);
        res.json({success: false, msg: 'Error creating csv'});
    } else {
        console.log('csv file saved');
        res.status(200);
        res.json({success:true, filename: filename});
    }
});
```

This creates the csv file correctly, I can open it in excel, but floating-point number are not written correctly and cant be used for SUM and other operations AND some of them are treated as DATE

formatting these numbers in excel via CTRL + 1 -> NUMBER doesnt help either, because then the values that were treated as DATE are completely off.

I tried adding the option excelStrings: true to the json2csv module, then the amounts are written correctly but are stringyfied (="0.456") and cannot be transformed into number either.

Any tips or advice I can try ?
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you share a few example lines of JSON input and CSV output (e.g. what you would get by opening in Notepad or something). It's not clear what format `expense.amount` is in. Also, you specify a Hungarian (?) date format but you don't specify the locale of the machine running Excel on which you are trying to open the CSV.

Comment: Check my answer for the solution, main problem was floating point instead of comma :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay I managed to find a solution,

I just had to make string from the amount and change the floating point to 'floating comma'
f.e.:

```
expenses.forEach(function(expense) {
  var amountFormatted = expense.amount + '';
  allExpenses.push({
    amount: amountFormatted.replace('.', ','),
    ...
  })
```